# How to convert jar file to war and deploy it in tomcat server

Tags: java, maven, jar, war, dropwizard

I am working on dropwizard-maven project.How can we convert the jar file to war file and deploy it in tomcat server.If anyone knows,kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just simply convert a jar file to a war file. A Web archive has a structure to be followed and there is no straight forward way to convert the type.

What you can do is, create a web application, import the jar file as dependency and make endpoints in the webapp to trigger calls in the jar you have.

You might need to take a look into why you are using dropwizard, if you are planning to deploy it in a tomcat server.

You might find the below link helpful.

https://github.com/twilio/wiztowar

Answer (score 0):

Add maven war plugin in your pom.xml and run command clean install to generate war file.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [wizard in a box](https://github.com/rvs-fluid-it/wizard-in-a-box), it will let you deploy a Dropwizard application to a Tomcat container as a war.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a Spring project, Add this to pom.xml.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not related to drop wizard, but if you are having a Spring boot project and you came here from google, this is what you should do.

1. Change the packaging to `WAR`

```xml
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

2. Mark the tomcat embedded server as `provided`

```xml
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
 <scope>provided</scope> <!-- This is important. -->
</dependency>
```

3. Make your `@SpringBootApplication` extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(HelloWorldApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class);
    }
}
```

I have a detailed article about [Converting Jar to War](https://springhow.com/convert-spring-boot-jar-in-to-war/)